# set image as background on drawer navigator menu on react navigation

Tags: image, menu, background, react-navigation, drawer

How to set image as background on react-navigation drawer menu?

I'm using expo, with react navigation ^4.0.10

The menu should contain a png image as a BackgroundImage, (FullScreen)

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Drawer Component in react-navigation.Check the example of custom drawer component in react-navigation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-navigator.html#providing-a-custom-contentcomponent)

```js
const DrawerNavigatorExample = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    //Drawer Optons and indexing
    NavScreen1: {
      screen: FirstActivity_StackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 1',
      },
    },
    NavScreen2: {
      screen: Screen2_StackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 2',
      },
    },
    NavScreen3: {
      screen: Screen3_StackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: 'Demo Screen 3',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    //For the Custom sidebar menu we have to provide our CustomSidebarMenu
    contentComponent: CustomSidebarMenu,
    //Sidebar width
    drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - 130,
  }
);

const CustomSidebarMenu=()=><ImageBackground source={{uri:'imgbg'}}><Text>Drawer</Text></ImageBackground>
```